# How to sort a 2D array using bubble sort?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, 2d

I need to sort a 2D array in descending order by row using bubble sort based on the last column but I'm having some trouble with it.

This is the data that I need to arrange in descending order but only based on the last column.

```
6814.00      85.00      86.00      92.00      88.00      87.75
7234.00      76.00      81.00      84.00      78.00      79.75
6465.00      87.00      54.00      68.00      72.00      70.25
7899.00      92.00      90.00      88.00      86.00      89.00
9901.00      45.00      78.00      79.00      80.00      70.50
8234.00      77.00      87.00      84.00      98.00      86.50
7934.00      76.00      91.00      84.00      65.00      79.00
7284.00      56.00      81.00      87.00      98.00      80.50
7654.00      76.00      87.00      84.00      88.00      83.75
3534.00      86.00      81.00      84.00      73.00      81.00
```

This is what I have so far.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
      if(arr1[i][5] < arr1[i+1][5])
      {
        int temp = arr1[i][j];
        arr1[i][j] = arr1[i+1][j];
        arr1[i+1][j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

But this is what I get, which clearly isn't working.

```
    6814.00      85.00      86.00      92.00      88.00      87.75
    7234.00      76.00      81.00      84.00      78.00      79.75
    7899.00      92.00      90.00      88.00      86.00      89.00
    9901.00      45.00      78.00      79.00      80.00      70.50
    8234.00      77.00      87.00      84.00      98.00      86.50
    7934.00      76.00      91.00      84.00      65.00      79.00
    7284.00      56.00      81.00      87.00      98.00      80.50
    7654.00      76.00      87.00      84.00      88.00      83.75
    3534.00      86.00      81.00      84.00      73.00      81.00
    6465.00      87.00      54.00      68.00      72.00      70.00
```

I also noticed that some of the numbers in the last column got rounded up and I'm not sure why. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Do you want to sort the matrix row wise or column wise? For sorting there is an inbuilt function sort(array name, length) by STL in algorithm.h

Comment: Row wise please.

Comment: I have to use bubble sort because it’s a project for school.

Comment: Do you have any complexity issues?

Comment: I don’t think so?

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the order of the last column, just check the last column, then move the entire row accordingly:

```
void BubbleSort2D(double arr1[][]){
    for(int m=0; m<10; m++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
          {
              if(arr1[i][5] < arr1[i+1][5])
              {
                for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                  double temp = arr1[i][j];
                  arr1[i][j] = arr1[i+1][j];
                  arr1[i+1][j] = temp;
                }
              }
          }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    double[][] arr2D = { {6814.00,      85.00,      86.00,      92.00,      88.00,      87.75},
            {7234.00,      76.00,      81.00,      84.00,      78.00,      79.75},
            {6465.00 ,     87.00,      54.00,      68.00,      72.00,      70.25},
            {7899.00,      92.00,      90.00,      88.00,      86.00,      89.00},
            {9901.00,      45.00,      78.00,      79.00,      80.00,      70.50},
            {8234.00,      77.00,      87.00,      84.00,      98.00,      86.50},
            {7934.00,      76.00,      91.00,      84.00,      65.00,      79.00},
            {7284.00,      56.00,      81.00,      87.00,      98.00,      80.50},
            {7654.00,      76.00,      87.00,      84.00,      88.00,      83.75},
            {3534.00,      86.00,      81.00,      84.00,      73.00,      81.00} };
    driver.BubbleSort2D(arr2D);
    for(int m=0; m<9; m++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
          {
            System.out.print(arr2D[m][i] + "  ");
          }
        System.out.println();
          }
}
```

Output:

7899.0  92.0  90.0  88.0  86.0  89.0
6814.0  85.0  86.0  92.0  88.0  87.75
8234.0  77.0  87.0  84.0  98.0  86.5
7654.0  76.0  87.0  84.0  88.0  83.75
3534.0  86.0  81.0  84.0  73.0  81.0
7284.0  56.0  81.0  87.0  98.0  80.5
7234.0  76.0  81.0  84.0  78.0  79.75
7934.0  76.0  91.0  84.0  65.0  79.0
9901.0  45.0  78.0  79.0  80.0  70.5

Comment: So would I add another for loop or something?

Comment: Sure. In the worst case it would take 10 iterations, so just add another 10-loop around the whole thing. I'll edit the snippet.

Comment: As an aside you should replace all the references to numbers like 9 or 6 with length checks to that array.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is you can take a whole row at a time and then sort it.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    int array[6];
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
         array[j] = arr1[i][j];
    }
    for(i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<(n-i-1); j++)
        {
             if(array[j]>array[j+1])
             {
                 temp=array[j];
                 array[j]=array[j+1];
                 array[j+1]=temp;
             }
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
         arr1[i][j] = array[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: What would n be in this case? Do I just initialize it like int n; or do I have to set it to something?

Comment: sorry for my mistake, n should be the length of array i.e., 6

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
for(int i = 1; i <=9; i++)
      {
        for(int j = 9; i <= j; j--) //edit.
        {
          if(arr1[j][5] > arr1[j-1][5])
          {
            for(int k = 0; k <= 5; k++)
            {               
                int temp = arr1[j][k];
                arr1[j][k] = arr1[j-1][k];
                arr1[j-1][k] = temp;    
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn’t work. It gave me a exit-1 thing in return.